# kR^i in Tamil using xelatex

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, tamil

I am trying to get kR^i as in kR^iShNa in Tamil. This is written as kru followed by an inverted comma, i.e. kru'. Following is my program

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily{\sst}[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\newfontfamily{\nst}[Script=Tamil]{Noto Sans Tamil}

\begin{document}
{\sst कृष्ण}\\
{\nst க்ருʼஷ்ண}
\end{document}
```

When I run the above program using xelatex, I don't get the inverted comma. Only a blank square shows up.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I don't speak/write Tamil and I don't know anything about the grammar, but Wikipedia seems to write கிருஷ்ணர் (copied from https://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%9F%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%A3%E0%AE%A9%E0%AF%8D), maybe for your use case that would also work? Forgive me if I make a bad suggestion.

Comment: The character `ʼ` (U+02BC) is not in the font.

Comment: Unrelated: Sanskrit 2003 does not have the more modern, and corrected, font features for doing ligatures properly.

Comment: Which font, in your opinion (Cicada), is the best and good-looking Sanskrit font that has most ligatures.

Comment: @Sundar  Opinion will vary, according to person, purpose and perspective, so I cannot say what suits me will suit you. Explore. Look for fonts with the `dev2` feature. `Shobhika` has an elegant design and also has Vedic accents (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380369/how-to-create-vedic-accents-anudatta-svarita-and-double-svarita-in-devanaga/522655). Unrelated: use `@` to ping a user, so that they get a notification in their inbox.

Comment: @Cicada I am using Shobhika and it is indeed wonderful. Could you please provide your recommendations for Kannada, Telugu, Tamil, Malayalam, Roman and Grantha fonts. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Sundar A big question! Do you mean when writing different scripts together in one document? The Noto fonts are designed to harmonise that way. Or perhaps you mean something like a specimen sheet (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/tamil-tex-in-windows) for the user to select from as suitable for the occasion and purpose? Display text for headings, body text, decorative, emphasis, one style or another style. The answer will go with the purpose and will take time. Also, in some cases, some fonts will need further development by the font maintainer, e.g., for specific conjuncts.

Comment: An important tip is to add the command `\tracinglostchars=2` near the top of your document. Then, you’ll get a warning on the console when a glyph is missing from the font, and which one. Without that, it's buried in the `.log` file.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround could be to use a matching font that contains the character:

[image: Matching font]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily{\sst}[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Sans Devanagari}%Sanskrit 2003}
\newfontfamily{\nst}[Script=Tamil]{Noto Sans Tamil}
\newfontfamily\fextra{Noto Sans}
\newcommand\apostrophe{{\fextra ʼ}}
\begin{document}
\

{\sst कृष्ण}

{\nst க்ருʼஷ்ண}

{\nst க்ரு\apostrophe ஷ்ண}

\end{document}
```

---

*edited*

To add to the comment about which fonts to use:

The answer will vary according to the desired purpose and usage. One answer will not fit everybody for all cases. It will be a matter for selection and choice.

For example, Pria Ravichandran's `Catamaran` font at Google Fonts is a sans text font with Latin and Tamil and comes in various weights.

The other fonts at Google Fonts are worth checking out. And, of course, Google's own `Noto` are worth a look too.

[image: Catamaran and some others]

The GIST fonts at CDAC are also worth a look.

They come in various styles.

For example, for Tamil:

[image: GIST TMOT]

and

[image: GIST TMOT2]

Each style suited to its purpose.

Check out the other GIST fonts.

Also, look in other Centres of Excellence, too.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont[Script=Tamil]{Noto Serif Tamil}
\newfontfamily\tamilfontsf[Script=Tamil]{Noto Sans Tamil}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}

\newcommand\fztaname{Catamaran}%Baloo Thambi}
\newcommand\fxtaname{Catamaran Black}
\newcommand\fctaname{Catamaran ExtraBold}
\newcommand\fvtaname{Catamaran SemiBold}
\newcommand\fbtaname{Catamaran Medium}
\newcommand\fntaname{Catamaran Light}
\newcommand\fmtaname{Catamaran ExtraLight}
\newcommand\fmmtaname{Catamaran Thin}

\newcommand\ftbname{ETTamilNew}
\newcommand\ftcname{Kavivanar}
%\newcommand\ftdname{落落补 汤圆}%{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTParvathi}}
\newcommand\ftename{SakalBharati}
\newcommand\ftfname{\detokenize{TSCu_SaiIndira}}
%
%



\newfontface\fzta{\fztaname}
\newfontface\fxta{\fxtaname}
\newfontface\fcta{\fctaname}
\newfontface\fvta{\fvtaname}
\newfontface\fbta{\fbtaname}
\newfontface\fnta{\fntaname}
\newfontface\fmta{\fmtaname}
\newfontface\fmmta{\fmmtaname}

\newfontface\ftb{\ftbname}
\newfontface\ftc{\ftcname}
%\newfontface\ftd{\ftdname}
\newfontface\fte{\ftename}
\newfontface\ftf{\ftfname}

\newcommand\sampletext{சூரியக் குடும்பம்}

\newcommand\gaftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTAbhirami}}
\newcommand\gbftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTAmala}}
\newcommand\gcftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTAppar}}
\newcommand\gdftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTChanakya}}
\newcommand\geftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTChandra}}
\newcommand\gfftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTHeena}}
\newcommand\ggftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTIlango}}
\newcommand\ghftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTKalyani}}
\newcommand\giftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTKamal}}
\newcommand\gjftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTKannadasan}}
\newcommand\gkftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTKannagi}}
\newcommand\glftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTKomala}}
\newcommand\gmftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTKrishnan}}
\newcommand\gnftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTKumudam}}
\newcommand\goftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTLalitha}}
\newcommand\gpftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTMadhura}}
\newcommand\gqftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTMina}}
\newcommand\grftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTNambi}}
\newcommand\gsftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTPadma}}
\newcommand\gtftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTParvathi}}
\newcommand\guftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTPattinathar}}
\newcommand\gvftcname{\detokenize{GIST-TMOTSuman}}


\newfontface\gaftc{\gaftcname}
\newfontface\gbftc{\gbftcname}
\newfontface\gcftc{\gcftcname}
\newfontface\gdftc{\gdftcname}
\newfontface\geftc{\geftcname}
\newfontface\gfftc{\gfftcname}
\newfontface\ggftc{\ggftcname}
\newfontface\ghftc{\ghftcname}
\newfontface\giftc{\giftcname}
\newfontface\gjftc{\gjftcname}
\newfontface\gkftc{\gkftcname}
\newfontface\glftc{\glftcname}
\newfontface\gmftc{\gmftcname}
\newfontface\gnftc{\gnftcname}
\newfontface\goftc{\goftcname}
\newfontface\gpftc{\gpftcname}
\newfontface\gqftc{\gqftcname}
\newfontface\grftc{\grftcname}
\newfontface\gsftc{\gsftcname}
\newfontface\gtftc{\gtftcname}
\newfontface\guftc{\guftcname}
\newfontface\gvftc{\gvftcname}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=tamil,changecounternumbering=true]{tamil}
\setotherlanguages{english}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textenglish{\fztaname} & \huge\fzta\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\fxtaname} & \huge\fxta\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\fctaname} & \huge\fcta\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\fvtaname} & \huge\fvta\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\fbtaname} & \huge\fbta\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\fntaname} & \huge\fnta\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\fmtaname} & \huge\fmta\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\fmmtaname} & \huge\fmmta\sampletext \\
\\
\textenglish{\ftbname} & \huge\ftb\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\ftcname} & \huge\ftc\sampletext \\
%\textenglish{\ftdname} & \huge\ftd\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\ftename} & \huge\fte\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\ftfname} & \huge\ftf\sampletext \\
\end{tabular}

\newpage
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textenglish{\gaftcname} & \huge\gaftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gbftcname} & \huge\gbftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gcftcname} & \huge\gcftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gdftcname} & \huge\gdftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\geftcname} & \huge\geftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gfftcname} & \huge\gfftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\ggftcname} & \huge\ggftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\ghftcname} & \huge\ghftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\giftcname} & \huge\giftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gjftcname} & \huge\gjftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gkftcname} & \huge\gkftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\glftcname} & \huge\glftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gmftcname} & \huge\gmftc\sampletext \\
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textenglish{\gnftcname} & \huge\gnftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\goftcname} & \huge\goftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gpftcname} & \huge\gpftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gqftcname} & \huge\gqftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\grftcname} & \huge\grftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gsftcname} & \huge\gsftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gtftcname} & \huge\gtftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\guftcname} & \huge\guftc\sampletext \\
\textenglish{\gvftcname} & \huge\gvftc\sampletext \\
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```