# Malayalam package

Tags: packages, languages, indic

Sorry if I am repeating, but I do not seem to see my post here. Does anybody know of a Malayalam language package. I am working on a Mac running Leopard.

Comment: AFAIK, texlive 2011 has support for indic script..

Comment: you can try this package, it uses phonetic transliteration.. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/malayalam-latex

Comment: Thank you, I shall try that. Phonetic transliteration is helpful. It is easier for me.

Comment: @VineetMenon: I think this should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://tug.org/pipermail/tugindia/2009-June/004840.html) thread from TUGIndia Mailing list should help you in the right direction. And, here are a couple of references from a Google search:

- See this [this](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/malayalam-latex) package on CTAN.
- There's also [this](http://sarovar.org/projects/malayalam) initiative by Government of India, funded by CTAN, working on Malayalam fonts; linked is the homepage for the project.

Typesetting Indic languages is still undergoing a lot of development. For instance, in case of Tamil language, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319/latex-xetex-setup-tamil-indic-languages) TeX.SX thread.

Comment: the third link(http://sarovar.org/projects/malayalam) seems to be inactive. Instead, one can use https://www.ctan.org/pkg/malayalam-omega  and fonts can be dowloaded from https://mathematicsschool.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/%E0%B4%A8%E0%B4%AE%E0%B5%81%E0%B4%95%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%95%E0%B5%8D-%E0%B4%92%E0%B4%B0%E0%B5%81%E0%B4%AE%E0%B4%BF%E0%B4%9A%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%9A%E0%B5%8D-%E0%B4%B2%E0%B5%87%E0%B4%9F%E0%B5%86%E0%B4%95%E0%B5%8D/