# Are there any other fonts for Tamil fractions?

Tags: xetex, unicode, indic, tamil, lualatex-dev

I'm Using TexLive2020 using the TexStudio editor in Linux. I can typeset in Tamil using Xelatex and Lualatex.I was able to typeset the Tamil fraction ([LaTeX/XeTeX setup Tamil/Indic languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319/latex-xetex-setup-tamil-indic-languages)) as mentioned in the Tamil supplement block using the Lohit Tamil Chart font. I want to know is there any other Tamil fonts for typesetting in Tamil Fractions so that it looks uniform when typesetting my document.

P.S: So far only Lohit Tamil Chart works for the Tamil Fractions.

Comment: I don't think this is on topic, but google NOTO family have added a font for this block see https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/1532

Comment: Thank you for your reply David. I installed the font, it works in LuaLatex while in Xelatex it gives an error "Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansTamilSupplementRegular"  cannot be(fontspec) found.

Comment: you may need to run `fc-cache` so xetex can find the file via fntconfig,also check the name carefully (and try using the filename with extension not the internal font name) it will work but xetex is a lot more fussy about font names than luatex which is more forgiving in its search rules.

Comment: When Running   `fc-match`  on Noto Sans Tamil Supplement font it gives Dejavu Serif as the font. I guess I've to check and edit the fontconfig file to fix that error.