# Writing tamil in LaTeX using my english keyboard

Tags: tamil

I have come across previous posts ([LaTeX/XeTeX setup Tamil/Indic languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319/latex-xetex-setup-tamil-indic-languages)) where Tamil could be written. I currently have the US layout English keyboard on my computer. Is there some way to somehow still type in Tamil?

I mean similar to, say, Greek alphabets where I can (with some effort), write `\alpha`, `\beta`, etc., in math-mode and construct words and sentences. Is there someway to use a backslash and a combination of alphabets to generate a Tamil alphabet. For example, something like `\a` to generate `அ`, and so forth?

I currently use Linux,and use PdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022).

Comment: you really should consider switching to a unicode Tex such as luatex for languages such as Tamil the possibilities with pdftex are far more limited whatever keyboard input you use

Comment: see itrans example here for Tamil using transliterated Roman input https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1594/1090